# how to use count and or expression at same time golang mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, go

hi i write this line of codes but when i try it just return when total is greater then number i gave and it just doesn't use checked . i mean i have 6 documants and 5 of them are true but it give me 6 reuslt !

```
checked := bson.D{{"$or", []interface{}{bson.D{{"checked", false}}, bson.D{{"checked", nil}}}}}
totalReport := bson.D{{"total", bson.D{{"$gte", config.ReportNumberToChangeNickname}}}}
totalReportAndChecked := bson.D{{"$and", []interface{}{checked, totalReport}}}
matchStage := bson.D{{"$match", totalReportAndChecked}}
groupStage := bson.D{{"$group", bson.D{{"_id", "$user_id"}, {"total", bson.D{{"$sum", 1}}}}}}
cursor, err := UserReportDb.Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{groupStage, matchStage})
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return &mongo.Cursor{}, err
}
```

Comment: Did you check the mongo db query's you are passing you can wrap up all the conditions in one query and it will be much faster. Kindly view the docs for the operations here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

Comment: thanks i found answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer thanks

```
cond := bson.D{{"$cond", []interface{}{"$checked", 0, 1}}}

matchStage := bson.D{{"$match", bson.D{{"$expr", bson.D{{"$gte", []interface{}{"$total", config.ReportNumberToChangeNickname}}}}}}}

groupStage := bson.D{{"$group", bson.D{{"_id", "$user_id"}, {"total", bson.D{{"$sum", cond}}}, {"value", bson.D{{"$last", "$value"}}}}}}

cursor, err := UserReportDb.Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{groupStage, matchStage})
```